# Intuition behind Evidence function

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I understand the formal definition of Evidence function. If we define an experiment $E= \{X,\theta, f(x\mid\theta)\},$ where $X$ is a random vector with pmf $f(x\mid\theta)$ with parameter $\theta,$ then for any particular $X = x$ will give some evidence about $\theta$ using evidence function, $\operatorname{Ev}(E, x).$ Can anyone explain the intuition behind it with a proper example?

Comment: What is the formal definition? I fail to find one via google.

Comment: @Hurkyl : I think this may be the same thing that is discussed in the textbook of Casella & Berger (not Jim Berger of Duke, but Roger Berger of NCSU, I think), and in various published discussions of the likelihood principle. I suspect there's not much to say about this function and that's why people might find it confusing.